# Why do I get nothing with $('#leftquota').val()?

Tags: jquery, css

```
<span id="leftquota" style="display:none" value="$row[available]">$row[available]</span>
```

JQuery code:

```
var left=$('#leftquota').val();
alert(left);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var left=$('#leftquota').attr('value'); alert(left);
```

is what you want.

The .attr() method gets(or sets) an attribute of a element. So .attr('value') will get the value of the 'value' attribute.

EDIT: As morning coffee pointed out, the same value of the 'value' attribute is given inside the span.

So we should do

```
var left=$('#leftquota').text(); alert(left);
```

to get the value.

Also, 'value' is not a valid attribute for the span tag.

Answer (score 1):

Because `val()` takes the value from an input field. `value` is not a valid attribute of `<span>`.

You should use `.text()` since you store the same information as in the value-field inside your `<span>`.

**Example**:

```
var left = $('#leftquota').text();
alert(left);
```